# Java eclipse, how to view just properties you care about in a list in debug Expressions/Inspect. LINQ analog

Tags: java, eclipse

This has to do with inspecting lists of complex objects, viewing one property only.
In Visual studio, C# with LINQ I can do this during debugging in the Watch:

```
list.Select(x => x.PropOfInterest).ToList()
```

[image: Using LINQ in Watch]

A colleague's suggestion was doing something like:

```
    getList().stream().map(x -> x.getInterestingProperty())
```

But that doesn't work in the Expressions in Eclipse, because "Lambda expressions cannot be used in an evaluation expression".

What's the best way to inspect a generic list like that during debugging in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Great question. Here is what you can do.

1. Implement a small class that implements `java.util.function.Function<T, String>` whose `apply()` method returns the property you want. Something like this:

   ```
   private static class F implements Function<Action, String>{
       @Override
       public String apply( Action t ){
           return t.getName();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then during debugging, use the following watch expression: `getList().stream().map( new F() ).collect( java.util.stream.Collectors.toList() )`

(You may try to make it general by using generics, I guess. I will be trying that anyhow on my system.)

---

**Edit:** Here's a generic version of the class using which one field of any class may be shown in the watch expression evaluation (assuming that you have a `get*()` method for it in the Java bean format.) In the watch expression mentioned earlier, instead of `new F()`, pass `new F( "yourFieldName" )`. Like this: `getList().stream().map( new F( "propertyOfInterest" ) ).collect( java.util.stream.Collectors.toList() )`.

```
public class F<T> implements Function<T, Object>{
    private String fieldName;
    private String getMethodName;

    public F(String fieldName) {
        super();
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.getMethodName = "get" + fieldName.substring( 0, 1 ).toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring( 1 );
    }

    @Override
    public Object apply( T t ){
        try {
            return t.getClass().getMethod( getMethodName ).invoke( t );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.